# JavaScript repeat password validation: why is label being removed?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

The validation on this repeat password div is acting up. It works as it should in some situations and doesn't in others.

When "registering on this page" once the user makes inputs to the "password" line(whether it is the required length of 8 or not) the "repeat password" line will display an error upon input. This error message displays in yellow above the input and beneath the "repeat password" label. The yellow error message removes as it should (leaving the "repeat password" label remaining) once the user ensures that the two passwords match(again, whether or not the first password input is valid). This also continues to work properly upon submission of the form if there are errors that make the "repeat password" error appear.

However, there are problems that occur if the "repeat password" input is empty while the first password input is also empty: the label for "repeat password" disappears.

For instance, if all the field are left blank and the user submits: the "repeat password" label disappears(no yellow error message either).

Also, if all inputs are valid, after submission and form reset: the "repeat password" label disappears.

Below is the code (JavaScript and HTML):

```js
   /* Register Validation */

function checkField(field) {
    if (!field.checkValidity()) {
        addError(field);
    } else {
        removeError(field);
    }
}   

function checkMatch() {
    const registerForm = document.getElementById("register-form");
    
    const passwordOneInput = registerForm.passwordone;
    
    const passwordTwoInput = registerForm.passwordtwo;
        
    if (passwordOneInput.value !== passwordTwoInput.value) {
        if (passwordTwoInput.previousElementSibling &&
            passwordTwoInput.previousElementSibling.className === 'error') {
                // error message already showing
            return;
            }
        const error = document.createElement('div');
        error.innerHTML = passwordTwoInput.dataset.errorMsg;
        error.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        error.style.borderRadius = '0.2em';
        error.style.width = 'fit-content';
        error.className = 'error';
        passwordTwoInput.parentNode.insertBefore(error, passwordTwoInput);
    } else {
        passwordTwoInput.previousElementSibling.remove();
        
    }
}

 function addError(field) {
    if (field.previousElementSibling &&
        field.previousElementSibling.className === 'error') {
            // error message already showing
        return;
        }
    const error = document.createElement('div');
    error.innerHTML = field.dataset.errorMsg;
    error.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    error.style.borderRadius = '0.2em';
    error.style.width = 'fit-content';
    error.className = 'error';
    field.parentNode.insertBefore(error, field);
}
        
function removeError(field) {
    if (field.previousElementSibling &&
        field.previousElementSibling.className === 'error') {
        field.previousElementSibling.remove();
    }
}
        
    
    
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    const registerForm = document.getElementById("register-form");
    const emailInput = registerForm.emailregister;
    emailInput.dataset.errorMsg = 'Enter a valid email address';
    const passwordOneInput = registerForm.passwordone;
    passwordOneInput.dataset.errorMsg = 'Password must be at least 8 characters';
    const passwordTwoInput = registerForm.passwordtwo;
    passwordTwoInput.dataset.errorMsg = 'Password does not match';
    const termsInput = registerForm.terms;
    termsInput.dataset.errorMsg = 'You must check the box to proceed'; 
        
    
    emailInput.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
        checkField(emailInput);
    });
        
    passwordOneInput.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
        checkField(passwordOneInput);
    });

    passwordTwoInput.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
        checkMatch();
    });

    termsInput.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
        checkField(termsInput);
    });

        
    
    registerForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        checkField(emailInput);
        checkField(passwordOneInput);
        checkMatch();
        checkField(terms);
        
    
        if (!registerForm.checkValidity()) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Please fix form errors.');}
        else {registerForm.submit;
            registerForm.reset();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
   


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index-styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" 
      integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="login.js"></script>
<title>Play2Learn Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1><img src="logo.png" alt="logo"></h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="border" href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
                <li id="games-li"><a class="border" href="#">Games</a> 
                    <ul id="games-ul">
                        <li><a href="games/anagram-hunt.html">Anagram Hunt </a></li>
                        <li><a href="games/math-facts.html">Math Facts Practice</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a class="border" href="about.html">About</a></li> 
                <li><a href="login.html">Login </a></li> 
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
<main>
    <div id="login-div" class="form-div">
        <h2>Log In</h2>
            <article id="article3">
                <form id="login-form" method="post" action="javascript:alert('Form Submitted. You are now logged in.')" novalidate>
                    <div>
                        <label for="emaillogin">Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" name="emaillogin" id="emaillogin" size="25" required>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="passwordlogin">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" name="passwordlogin" id="passwordlogin" size="25" minlength="8" required>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a href="#" id="login-toggle">Need an account? Register</a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" value="Login">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </article>
    </div>
    <div id="register-div" class="form-div">
        <h2>Register</h2>
            <article id="article3">
                <form id="register-form" method="post" action="javascript:alert('Form Submitted. Check your email to complete registration.')" novalidate>
                    <div>
                        <label for="emailregister">Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" name="emailregister" id="emailregister" size="25" required>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="passwordone">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" name="passwordone" id="passwordone" minlength="8" size="25" required>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="passwordtwo">Repeat Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" name="passwordtwo" id="passwordtwo" minlength="8" size="25" required>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" required>
                        <label for="terms" class="required">
                            I am at least 8 years old.</label>
                        
                    
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a href="#" id="register-toggle">Already have an account? Login</a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" value="Register">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </article>
    </div>


</main>
<footer>
    <div class="footer">
        &#169 2021 Play2Learn
        <a href="contact-us.html" title="Contact Us"><i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i></a>
        <a href="https://instagram.com" title="Instagram"><i class="fab fa-instagram-square"></i></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com" title="Twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
        <a href="https://facebook.com" title="Facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you really have your `meta` and `link` elements prior to your `doctype`? If so, that's invalid. They need to be in the `head` section.

Comment: No. Error during copy/paste.